# php ternary operator explanation

Tags: php

I am confused. I had set up the following code in my index.php to auto switch between xampp and server database config files:

```
define('ENVIRONMENT', isset($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])=='my_domain_name.com' ? 'production' : 'development');

    echo 'SERVER_NAME  '.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; // getting localhost
    echo 'env '.ENVIRONMENT; // getting production.
```

In Xampp locally, I thought this would result in  the ENVIRONMENT constant set to 'development' with $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']=localhost. Would someone mind explaining what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
define('ENVIRONMENT', isset($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])=='my_domain_name.com' ? 'production' : 'development');
```

Here you're comparing the result of `isset()` to `'my_domain_name.com'`; you're comparing a boolean to a string.

What you want is to check "*is `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` set AND is `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` equal to `my_domain_name.com`?*", as follows:

```
define('ENVIRONMENT', (isset($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']) && $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'my_domain_name.com') ? 'production' : 'development');
```

*(Or... just remove the `isset()` entirely.)*

Comment: That was basically my answer, along with encasing the comparison in parenthesis for better readability (which I think is why the OP went snow blind to it). But removing the `isset()` kind of obviates that.

Comment: @TimPost Agreed; in general, I'm very, very anal about my brackets, and I do think this was the result of a readability issue. I'm actually going to add those parens to my post, good call.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `isset` in this case (you know it's set already):

```
define('ENVIRONMENT', 
    ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']) == 'my_domain_name.com' ? 'production' : 'development'
);
```

Comment: Definitely shouldn't use `isset` here as its absence ought to be logged.

Comment: Why the parens around `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
define('ENVIRONMENT', ((isset($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']) && ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']=='my_domain_name.com')) ? 'production' : 'development'));
```